# Custom treeview draw bug on mouseover collapse/expand glyph

Tags: vb.net, treeview, mouseover, ondraw, glyph

I'm overiding the node draw event for a treeview in draw all mode such as the code below.

```
 Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawNode(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawTreeNodeEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim Indent = e.Node.Level * Me.Indent + 32
        Dim font = Me.Font
        'draw selected
        If e.State And TreeNodeStates.Selected Then
            Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, e.Bounds.Location.Y, Me.Width - 1, e.Bounds.Height - 1)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, rect)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkSlateBlue, rect)
        End If


        'draw status icon
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Me.ImageList.Images(e.Node.ImageIndex), New Point(e.Bounds.X + indent - Me.ImageList.ImageSize.Width + 2, e.Bounds.Y + ((Me.ItemHeight / 2) - (Me.ImageList.ImageSize.Height / 2))))

        'draw collapse glyph
        If e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
            Dim element As VisualStyleElement
            Dim glyphRect = New Rectangle(e.Bounds.Location.X + 2 + e.Node.Level * Me.Indent, e.Bounds.Location.Y + 8, 16, 16)
            If e.Node.IsExpanded Then
                element = VisualStyleElement.TreeView.Glyph.Opened
            Else
                element = VisualStyleElement.TreeView.Glyph.Closed
            End If

            Dim renderer As New VisualStyleRenderer(element)
            renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, glyphRect)
        End If

        If e.Node.Level.Equals(0) Then
            font = New Font(Me.Font.Name, 12, FontStyle.Regular)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, font, Brushes.MidnightBlue, New Point(indent + 5, e.Bounds.Location.Y + 5), New StringFormat())
        ElseIf e.Node.Level.Equals(1) Then
            'action
            Dim params = CType(e.Node, ActionNode).Params

            Dim x = indent + 5
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, New Point(x, e.Bounds.Location.Y + 2), New StringFormat())
            For Each param In params
                e.Graphics.DrawString(param.Key & ":", Me.Font, Brushes.DarkSlateBlue, New Point(x, e.Node.Bounds.Location.Y + 15))
                x += e.Graphics.MeasureString(param.Key & ":", Me.Font).Width - 1
                e.Graphics.DrawString(param.Value, Me.Font, Brushes.SlateGray, New Point(x, e.Node.Bounds.Location.Y + 15))
                x += e.Graphics.MeasureString(param.Value, Me.Font).Width
            Next

        ElseIf e.Node.Level.Equals(2) Then
            'assertion
            Dim params = CType(e.Node, AssertionNode).Params

            Dim x = indent + 5
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, New Point(x, e.Bounds.Location.Y + 2), New StringFormat())
            For Each param In params
                e.Graphics.DrawString(param.Key & ":", Me.Font, Brushes.DarkSlateBlue, New Point(x, e.Node.Bounds.Location.Y + 15))
                x += e.Graphics.MeasureString(param.Key & ":", Me.Font).Width - 1
                e.Graphics.DrawString(param.Value, Me.Font, Brushes.SlateGray, New Point(x, e.Node.Bounds.Location.Y + 15))
                x += e.Graphics.MeasureString(param.Value, Me.Font).Width
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

This draws the tree view exactly as I want it but for some reason wen you mouse over the open/close elements the node seems get redrawn but over the top of its last redraw causing the text to look bolded and an outline around any images. This only happens however if the node is not selected and if it is selected then everything is fine. Sorry new user can't post screen dump.

I'm not sure if you can hook into the mouseover glyph event to just invalidate the control of even detect the sender on the draw event but im out of idears now.

Tried:

- Clearing the graphics object on draw before drawing node
- Setting background rectangle and drawing the node just like when selected

Comment: You must draw the background, fill the entire e.Bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only really guess since you couldn't post an image, and the code you included isn't complete (ActioNode?  AssertionNode?).

I know you mentioned clearing the background, but the code you posted wasn't clearing the node area.  Try changing it to something like this, see if it works:

```
Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, e.Bounds.Top, Me.ClientSize.Width - 1, e.Bounds.Height - 1)
If e.State And TreeNodeStates.Selected Then
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, rect)
  e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkSlateBlue, rect)
Else
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, rect)
End If
```

Why are you ignoring all exceptions?

You also need to dispose your fonts.

Comment: Hello yes i took the clearing the graphics object out because it didn't seem to have any effect.I dont know why I didnt think of this as its the only bit of code thats different for a selected node which seems to work properly. Im not ignoring all exceptions i just put that in to see if or what exceptions were thrown to get more detail. Im just using the actual treeview font didnt know I needed to dispose that but will now thanks. Finaly sorry about the confusion with the action/assertion node. They are simply classes that inherit treenode to add some data needed when drawing nodes.